# $f(x) = {x^{2}-x-6\over x-2}$. can $f$ be defined at $x=2$ in such a way that $f$ is continuous at this point?(for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis

My answer to this question was that $f$ can not be continuous at this point since $x=2$ is not defined. Therefore $f$ is not continuous at $x=2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: factor the numerator and you will see how.

Comment: @AxelFoley The problem with the way you answered this question is you are looking only at how the function is defined *now*.  The point of the problem is: can we somehow pick a value and define $f(2)$ to be that value such that this new function $f$ (which is the same as the old function, except this one is defined at $x = 2$) is continuous at $x = 2$?  It's certainly not continuous (or even defined) at $x = 2$ now, but can we somehow define $f(x)$ at $x = 2$ so that it is continuous at $x =2 $?

Comment: @user46944 i really apologize for this i made a mistake.the numerator is $x^{2}$+x-6 on the numerator in which we are left with x+3 if we factor it.so then i would say that it is defined since we have a value

Comment: @AxelFoley Alright, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2 - x-6 = (x-3)(x+2)$$ Since neither factor cancels with the denominator, $x=2$ is not a removable singularity.

However, if $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 +x-6}{x-2} = \frac{(x+3)(x-2)}{x-2} = x+3$$ then define $f(2) = 2+3=5$.

Comment: Good answer, but be honest.  If you were in the OP's shoes and had this question, would you honestly gain this great understanding of the problem and solution now after reading this answer?

Comment: @marwalix No, his answer is correct, but may be of little interest for the OP.

Comment: But this (most probably) gives the correct exercise, miscopied by the OP.

Comment: The OP made a mistake with $f(x)$.

Comment: This is confirmed: @Jordan correctly guessed the exercise the OP had in mind.

Comment: Well, I guess my original comment on this question was useless.  Looks like this answer was useful enough for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about this.

The function $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2 + x - 6}{x - 2}$ is currently *not* defined at $x = 2$.  But what about around $x = 2$?  If the function shoots up to $\infty$ or down to $-\infty$ on either side of $x = 2$, then we won't be able to "fill in the gap" and make $f$ continuous.

But if the function looks like a continuous function everywhere, but just has a hole at $x = 2$ (which, if we were to fill in the hole, it would be a continuous function everywhere), then we are good.

How can we go about checking if this function just has a hole at $x =2$, or if actually on one side or the other it shoots off to $\pm \infty$?

Well, that's the whole point of taking a limit.  To see where the function is approaching.  Let's take the left hand limit (i.e., $\lim \limits_{x \to 2^{-}} f(x)$) and the right hand limit ($\lim \limits_{x \to 2^{+}} f(x)$) and if these two are equal and neither are infinite, then we know the graph of the function looks like a continuous function everywhere except with a hole at $x = 2$ (which we could fill in by defining $f(2)$ as the value of the limit as $x \to 2$).

Ok, well $\lim \limits_{x \to 2^{+}} \dfrac{x^2 + x - 6}{x - 2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 2^{+}} \dfrac{(x + 3)(x - 2)}{x - 2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 2^{+}} x + 3 = 2 + 3 = 5$.

Similarly, $\lim \limits_{x \to 2^{-}} f(x) = 5$.  So both the right hand and left hand limit exist and are equal, which means the function looks continuous everywhere, except with a hole at $x = 2$.  To fill in the hole, we can just define $f(x)$ as $5$ when $x = 2$.  Then, $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} f(x) = 5 = f(2)$, and that shows that $f$ is continuous at $x = 2$.

Comment: so i was right ?the function cant be continuous at that point right?

Comment: @AxelFoley Double check and make sure the function $f(x)$ in your question is correctly written.  If so, you were right that there is no real number we can define $f(2)$ to be that would make the function continuous at $x = 2$.  So yes, you were right, but please make sure you understand *why* you were right.  The explanation you gave in your question for why wasn't correct.

Comment: Love the downvote from a stranger without any explanation.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

In order to extend continuously a function at a point where the denominator is zero (a pole), the function needs to have a finite limit at that limit. In the case we are looking at, the limit is $\infty$ and the answer to your question is negative

Comment: The OP made a mistake with $f(x)$.